# Good MEF Tutorials and Hands-on Labs?

Tags: .net, mef

I need some good MEF tutorials and hands-on labs, do you know of any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good one:
[MEF Tutorial and Hands On Lab](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2009/06/fan-ie-someone-not-on-team-mef-tutorial.html)

Comment: example that throws exceptions :(

Answer (score 3):

Check this out from CodePlex:

[MEF Hands-On Lab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VS2010TrainingCourse_IntroToMEF)